# Is there a cross-platform way of getting the java path in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Currently I am working on a .net core console app with a embedded jar. There is no such thing as a java console app, right? So I would want to run my jar file inside my console app. I know the .net process API but I don't know if there is an environment variable telling me the java runtime location so that I can execute it.

Registry keys are not cross-platform, please don't give answers using some Windows-only solutions, please.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME`? ....

Comment: I thought that `JAVA_HOME` needs to be set by the user...

Comment: Traditionally JAVA_HOME is an environment variable you can reference to lookup the path where JAVA is installed. The Java program would be installed in JAVA_HOME/bin/java. Java programs can run as a console app, please see http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11hello/HelloWorld.java.html

Comment: It does not matter what sets it - a user or an installation routine. But you don't have a better way to find where java is installed.

Comment: @Jason Oh... But I have already started ao it's no turn back :P

Comment: @zerkms So I should tell the user to set it if it does not exist?

Comment: Yep ...........

Comment: @Jeremy there is no such thing as a registry in .net core... why mark as duplicate? :(

Comment: Unless really necessary, you should convert the JAR to equivalent C#, or use IKVM to run it. Detecting Java runtime would be painful to maintain, but you definitely can check how ANTLR or other projects do.

Comment: @Lex Java is usually (if not always) backwards-compatible. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that Java runtime is no longer available everywhere. Due to its security issues, many systems can be Java free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get environment variables in a cross platform way using .NET Core

```
Console.WriteLine("JAVA_HOME: " + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME"));
```

As everyone is pointing out, making a cross platform 'runner' is a bad idea in that its difficult to maintain.

JAVA_HOME isn't created by default upon install, and it will be a flaky interface, but you could make it work.